# How to share attributes without an is-a relationship in Python?

Tags: python, properties

I have a number of Python types that describe a hierarchy in the sense that they are increasingly specific in terms of their properties. Instead of trying to describe it in words, here is an example:

```
class A:
    @property
    def prop1(self):
        return self._prop1

class B:
    @property
    def prop1(self):
        return self._prop1

    @property
    def prop2(self):
        return self._prop2

class C:
    @property
    def prop1(self):
        return self._prop1

    @property
    def prop2(self):
        return self._prop2

    @property
    def prop3(self):
        return self._prop3
```

So, as you go down the class list, `B` has all of the properties of `A` and then some extra ones. `C` has all of the properties of `B` and then some extra ones, and so on. I would like to minimize the duplication of the above definitions if possible.

One obvious solution would be to use inheritance, making `B` a subclass of `A` and so on. However, the semantics of these types do not follow an is-a relationship; I do not want `isinstance(bObject, A)` to be `True`. Is there an alternative way in Python to straightforwardly allow this sharing of attributes without using subclasses?

Comment: You could use composition instead of subclassing.

Comment: I suppose you mean that I could house an `A` inside of each `B`, and then reimplement `B`'s property accessors to pull from the `A` instance. That's the other solution that came to mind, but that doesn't seem any more compact than the implementation shown above.

Comment: Why do you really care what `isinstance` returns? Do you really have a good reason to be calling `isinstance` ever?

Comment: Probably not, but in case someone ever does, I don't want to lie and say that `C` is an `A` when it really isn't. The characteristics of the types don't fit the semantics of subclassing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a decorator:

```
def has_prop1(cls):
    @property
    def prop1(self):
        return self._prop1

    cls.prop1 = prop1

    return cls

@has_prop1
class A(object):
    pass
```

Compositing would go like this:

```
@has_prop1
@has_prop2
class B(object):
    pass
```

Or even like this:

```
def has_many_properties(cls):
    return has_prop1(has_prop2(has_prop3(cls)))

@has_many_properties
class C(object):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You say "I don't want to lie and say that C is an A when it really isn't. The characteristics of the types don't fit the semantics of subclassing." With your obscured example, it's not clear which way to go.

If you're saying this because there's additional functionality in `class A` that doesn't apply to `class C`, then I would hoist out the property part of the class compositionally, so you have `A`, `B`, `C` containing `AProps`, `BProps`, and `CProps` respectively, and give the property classes a proper inheritance relationship.

If there's no such additional functionality, and it's not just coincidental that the properties are built up the way you show, then mentally rename `class A` to `class ProvidesProp1`, note that `class C` is-a class that provides `prop1`, and accept that `class C` therefore is-a `class A`.